# Attempting to print a successful/unsuccessful after a simulation

Tags: python, simulation

I'm a relatively new python coder and I am having problems attempting to print successful_trades/unsuccessful_trades after a 10 second simulation. The only thing I can think of is making the line of code saying 'print("Successful ender pearl trade")' an operator (which obviously won't work). Any help would be greatly appreciated, code is below. Thank you!

```
import multiprocessing

import time

import random

successful_trades = 0
unsuccessful_trade = 0

# Your foo function
def foo(n):
 for i in range(10000 * n):
        print ("Tick")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start foo as a process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="Foo", args=(10,))
    p.start()

    # Wait 10 seconds for foo
    time.sleep(10)

    # Terminate foo
    p.terminate()

    # Cleanup
    p.join()



user_input = input()
if user_input == "o":
    while True:
     import random

     k = random.randint(1, 109)

     number = random.randint(1, 109)
     if str(number) == str(k):
         print("Successful ender pearl trade")
         (str(successful_trades) + str(1))
     if str(number) != str(k):
         print("Unsuccessful ender pearl trade")
         (str(unsuccessful_trade) + str(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

One theory is your infinite while loop is locking up the screen output.
You can test this by changing your while true loop to

```
for i in range(100):
```